# Using bombardier for server benchmarking - but can't add body parameters

Tags: debugging, go, benchmarking

So, I'm using [bombardier](https://github.com/codesenberg/bombardier) on MacOS Sierra
for server benchmarking from command line.
In this example i'm using 1 connection and 1 request, and two headers:
"Authorization" and "Content-Type" and body: "{isTemplate:1}"
But server does not receiving body.

```
./bombardier -c 1 -n 1 -m PATCH -H "Authorization: Bearer MYBEARERGOESHERE" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -b "{isTemplate:1}" http://localhost:8082/presentation/6525/update
```

I tried:

```
-b "{isTemplate:1}"

-b "isTemplate:1"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Probably a problem with your own server, the  `-b` option is the right one.

Comment: If `-b` stands for body and looking at your examples, I'd imagine you'd like to use JSON for your body. None of your examples is a valid JSON though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the solution, - you need to write body variables like this:

```
-b "isTemplate=1"
```

So final request:

```
./bombardier -c 1 -n 1 -m PATCH -H "Authorization: Bearer MYBEARERGOESHERE" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -b "isTemplate=1" http://localhost:8082/presentation/6525/update
```

Comment: is there any way to export commands for bombardier from insomnia or postman. or need to develop a new plugin for insomnia to do it?

Comment: unfortunately i don't know